# Is there a way to check that something has exported successfully in protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

In my application, there is a button that exports a csv file to my computer. Is there a way to check that the exported file has actually exported in protractor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fs (file System) module node provides for this purpose.

```
const fs = require('fs');
expect(fs.existsSync('path_to_your_download_location')).toBe(true, 'file does not exist in location')
```

[existsSync returns a boolean](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
async function verifyFileInDownloadsFolder(fileName: string) {
    const filePath = ('./e2e/app/tmp_downloads/' + fileName);
    await console.log('Getting the path ' + filePath);
    await browser.wait(async () => fs.existsSync(filePath), 10 * 10000, 'File never appeared!');
    await expect(fs.existsSync(filePath)).toBe(true,
        'Failed to download file: ' + fileName + ' in user directory' + filePath);
    await console.log('File download was successful');
}
```

Hope it helps you